# Include data collected prior to a custom dimension registration with GA4 Data API

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

I am using Google Analytics Data API to create reports for a GA4 property, and as soon as I set a filter for a user-scoped custom dimension, it excludes any data prior to the time the custom dimension was registered in GA.

I am seeing the same behavior in the [GA4 Query Explorer](https://ga-dev-tools.google/ga4/query-explorer/) tool, however, using the Explore section in Google Analytics UI for that same GA4 property when I set the same filters it does include the historical data all as `(not set)` for that dimension which is what I am expecting.

Is this expected and not something offered via the API and only available via the Exploration tool? Do I need to use a specific parameter so that all data regardless?